# Как вытащить почту при использовании Security протокола OAuth2?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth2

Подключил Basic Security на Spring Boot, и Oauth2 через google mail. Хочу класть в базу данных почты юзеров которые прошли Аутентефикацию через OAuth2. Как в коде это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любым удобным способом вызвать объект `Principal` и вытащить данные из него, примерно так:

```
OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
Authentication authentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();
Map<String, String> details = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) authentication.getDetails();
String email = details.get("email");
```

Comment: Хотелось бы не писать в каждом методе контроллера Principal. Сделать что-то вроде doFilter, но не знаю как туда засунуть Principal. Класс OAuth2Authentication который используется в решении деприкейтнут.

Comment: Копайте в сторону контекста спринг секьюрити, который вполне хранит в себе авторизацию пользователя. На ответ вопрос дан, то, что вы спрашиваете в комменте, если нужны разъяснения - новый вопрос с подробностями. Если мой ответ помог - отметьте его галочкой.